How to mock HashMap in JUnit test in Spring Boot (Throws nullpointerexception)
I have a problem to write JUnit test for the method in my Spring Boot example shown below. I cannot handle with the mock implementation in HashMap in JUnit test as it throws null pointer execption in url = MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl);
Here is the code snippet shown below
private static Map<String, String> MAP;

private static String clientURL = "CLIENT_URL";
private static String adminURL = "ADMIN_URL";

/**
 * Initializes the task list URLs based on the configuration properties.
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Map<String, String> tempMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    tempMap1.put("client", clientURL);
    tempMap1.put("admin", adminURL);
    MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap1);
}

public CustomResponse getResponse(RequestDTO request, String productType) {
        String url = "";
        if ("client".equalsIgnoreCase(productType)) {
            url = MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl);
        }else {
            url = MAP.getOrDefault(productType, adminURl);
        }
        return restTemplate.postForObject(url,
                request,
                CustomResponse.class);
}

Here is the JUnit test shown below
private static Map<String, String> MAP;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    MAP = new HashMap<>();
    MAP.put("client", "client-url");
    MAP.put("admin", "admin-url");
}

@Test
public void testGetResponseForClient() {
    // Given
    RequestDTO request = new RequestDTO (/* provide necessary parameters */);
    String productType = "client";
    String expectedUrl = "client-url";
    CustomResponse expectedResponse = new CustomResponse(200, "Success", new Object());

    // When
    when(MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl)).thenReturn(expectedUrl);  // ERROR_LINE
    when(restTemplate.postForObject(eq(expectedUrl), any(RequestDTO.class), eq(CustomResponse.class)))
            .thenReturn(expectedResponse);

    // Then
    CustomResponse response = service.getTaskList(request, productType);

    assertEquals(expectedResponse.getCode(), response.getCode());

    // Verify
    verify(restTemplate, times(1)).postForObject(expectedUrl, request, CustomResponse .class);
}

Here is the error in this line  ( when(MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl)).thenReturn(expectedUrl); )
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

How can I fix the issue ?
Revised Part
when(MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl)).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            String key = invocation.getArgument(0);
            return mockMap.getOrDefault(key, invocation.getArgument(1));
        });

This part throws the error shown below
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.


Why do you want to mock? Why not just use dependency injection to pass the map into the class that needs it?

@ndc85430 In getResponse , I use HashMap. How can I use depedency injection for map?

Pass it as a constructor parameter to the class that you need it in.

@ndc85430 I used init method to fill values. How can I do that ?

Call init() as part of the test setup.

That's the problem - you're creating the map inside the class. Don't. Just pass it into the constructor, so you can vary what you pass it for testing.

@ndc85430 I have to use MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl) in the method. How can I do that after I pass it into the constructor ?

@ndc85430 Is it possible to provide solution code ?

The error is occurring because MAP is a static field and you are trying to mock the behavior of MAP.getOrDefault() directly, which is not mockable using Mockito.
Try below changes
@Test
public void testGetResponseForClient() {
    // Given
    RequestDTO request = new RequestDTO(/* provide necessary parameters */);
    String productType = "client";
    String expectedUrl = "client-url";
    CustomResponse expectedResponse = new CustomResponse(200, "Success", new Object());

    // Mock MAP and define its behavior
    Map<String, String> mockMap = new HashMap<>();
    mockMap.put("client", expectedUrl);
    when(MAP.getOrDefault(anyString(), anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        String key = invocation.getArgument(0);
        return mockMap.getOrDefault(key, invocation.getArgument(1));
    });

    // When
    when(restTemplate.postForObject(eq(expectedUrl), any(RequestDTO.class), eq(CustomResponse.class)))
            .thenReturn(expectedResponse);

    // Then
    CustomResponse response = service.getResponse(request, productType);

    assertEquals(expectedResponse.getCode(), response.getCode());

    // Verify
    verify(restTemplate, times(1)).postForObject(expectedUrl, request, CustomResponse.class);
}


I tested your code but it didn't work.

I don't know if it helps or not : Could you please try using below syntax
Map<KeyType, ValueType> MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap1);

Where do I use it? I already used in init method of the service.

Map<String, String> tempMap1 = new HashMap<>();
tempMap1.put("client", clientURL);
tempMap1.put("admin", adminURL);
MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap1)
here you're using MAP

I already defined it in JUnit test class.

Sorry, I missed it.

Can you revise your code as it's wrong?

If you create your map in PostConstruct then it's insane to make it static.
In your Service:
private Map<String, String> map;

In your test:
@Test
public void testGetResponseForClient() {
    // Given (because u use Java 8 :))
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    myMap.put(productType, expectedUrl); 
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "map", myMap); 
    RequestDTO request = new RequestDTO (/* provide necessary parameters */);
    String productType = "client";
    String expectedUrl = "client-url";
    CustomResponse expectedResponse = new CustomResponse(200, "Success", new Object());

    // When
    when(restTemplate.postForObject(eq(expectedUrl), any(RequestDTO.class), eq(CustomResponse.class)))
            .thenReturn(expectedResponse);

    // Then
    CustomResponse response = service.getTaskList(request, productType);

    assertEquals(expectedResponse.getCode(), response.getCode());

    // Verify
    verify(restTemplate, times(1)).postForObject(expectedUrl, request, CustomResponse .class);
}


I already tried your approach but nothing changed. I got Null Pointerexception when I call MAP.getOrDefault(productType, clientUrl)

You should remove MAP and use map (not static prperty)

of method cannot be defined in Map  Map.of(productType, expectedUrl)

Did you import java.util.Map? Or some other Map?

And I hope you use at least Java 9 :)

I use Java 8 version .

Then Map<> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); myMap.put(productType, expectedUrl); ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "map", myMap);

I should use static map to fill it in init method. Can you revise it?

Your init method is not static, you can use not static map, but if you want use static- have a lot fun.
